# Tracing Importing issues in Python

Tags: python, import, trace

I have 2 external libraries in the same folder and I want to import them into the Python.
(i.e. "vtkCommonPython" and "vtkFilteringPython") and both of them have .pyd and .dll files.
(vtkCommonPython.pyd and vtkCommonPythonD.dll and same for other one)

Despite they are in same folder  when I write down

```
import vtkCommonPython
```

it is fine, however when I want to import other one

```
import vtkFilteringPython
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I tried also to find from where first library is loaded using

```
vtkCommonPython.__file__
```

And it was the same folder for the other one.

How I can trace the problem and find problem's source.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `-v` option to the python interpreter:

```
-v     : verbose (trace import statements) (also PYTHONVERBOSE=x)
```

as in:

```
python -v myscript.py
```

Comment: Thanks, what should I write in the interpreter? Since I can't write i.e. import -v ...

Comment: Just start the interpreter with **python -v**, then type your import statements.

Comment: Thanks, I used that and when I want to load second module I get the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found. How I can figure out where is the problem?